# ctex will not automatically new a paragraph using a blank line

Tags: pdftex, miktex, ctex

I have two computers installed **ctex** package while the versions are different. The versions are **2.5.2** and **2.4.16**. The MWE.tex saved as GBK encoding, is shown as follows.

```
\documentclass[GBK]{ctexbook}
\begin{document}
这里是第一段。

这里是第二段。
\end{document}
```

The one with version 2.4.16 (MikTex 2.9.7206, OS:Windows 10 64bit version 1903, Compile with **pdfLaTex**) outputs the expected result.
[image]

The problem is that the other with version 2.5.2 (MikTex 2.9.7429, OS:Windows 10 64bit version 2004, Compile with **pdfLaTex**) outpus the unexpected result.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to include the tags 'xetex' and 'miktex'. Not sure how relevant the following piece of information is, but when I compile your test document on a Mac (MacOS 10.15.5, MacTeX2020 with all updates applied), the empty line does trigger a paragraph break, as expected.

Comment: @Mico it seems that xelatx works well and it is only related to pdfLaTex. So I remove the "xetex" tag and add the "pdftex" tag. Thanks for your test and comment.

Comment: Why do you use the CTEX? Ten years out of date, please use Texlive2020.

Comment: Could this be an End of Line Sequence issue? Do you use the same editor on the two computers?

Comment: I don't have the fonts  so it doesn't work for me but I get an error abut bad UTF-8 unless I add `\UseRawInputEncoding` on the first line

Comment: @keth-tex Yes, the same editor, WinEdt.

Comment: @sikouhjw Texlive2020 is good however it requries everything UTF8 and I want to change the existting files which is GBK. Anyway, it is not the point that the OP concerns.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle adding "\UseRawInputEncoding" does not solve the problem.

Comment: the miktex and windows version differences you show are unlikely to make any difference, what are the versions of the latex format and the ctex class in the two cases?

Comment: What do you mean "the versions of the latex format" ? document class "ctexbook" is provided by ctex package whose versions are shown in the OP, i,e,, 2.4.16 (works) and 2.5.2 (not work).

Comment: @ZongxiangYi The best solution is to change the distribution. Chinese processing is much better now than it was ten years ago, so you should try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved just now by the ctex package maintainers as an [issue](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/518). It should be fixed in the next version 2.5.3. A temporary solution  provided by qinglee (user at github.com) is adding

> \endlinechar=13\relax

right after \documentclass. I have tested this solution and it works.

Moreover, ctex package with version 2.5.3 is now available in [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/pkg/ctex).